# Bootstrap 5 Images + Additional centered content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, layout, bootstrap-5

I'm currently in the process of learning Bootstrap (5) and attempting a more "[advanced](https://ibb.co/K27S3C5)" layout. The concept is two images side-by-side with titles below each and with a div centered **in-between** both. The end result will see them in a horizontal row of 3.

[Here's](https://ibb.co/K27S3C5) what I'm trying to achieve.

I have numerous variations of this but they all look as bad as each other, any guidance on this would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best I can come up with using your image. :)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />

    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row position-relative">
        <div class="image1 w-50 col-6"></div>
        <div class="image2 w-50 col-6"></div>
        <div
          class="circle rounded-circle position-absolute top-50 start-50 translate-middle"
        ></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="title1 col-6 text-center">Title 1</div>
        <div class="title2 col-6 text-center">Title 2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
  <style>
    .image1 {
      height: 300px;
      background: red;
    }
    .image2 {
      height: 300px;
      background: blue;
    }
    .circle {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      background: black;
    }
    .title1 {
      background: purple;
    }
    .title2 {
      background: green;
    }
  </style>
</html>
```